# How to use closurebuilder.py to compile my library with Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

Can't seem to find current information or a working solution to my problem. I'm trying to compile all the scripts in my /src directory as a standalone JavaScript library (as opposed to a Closure application). Although I am setting the flag `--output_mode=compiled`, the output of the compilation still has

```
var COMPILED=!0
```

Here's how I'm compiling:

1 - Concat all my .js files into a single file in ./tmp/concat.js
2 - Run concat.js through the compiler with the following command

```
./lib/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py \
     --root=/usr/local/google-closure/closure-library/ \
     --root=./tmp \
     --namespace=BB.go \
     --output_mode=compiled \
     --compiler_jar=/usr/local/google-closure/compiler.jar \
     --compiler_flags="--compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS" \
     --compiler_flags="--create_source_map=bb.js.map" \
     --compiler_flags="--warning_level=VERBOSE" \
     --compiler_flags="--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5" \
 > bb.min.js
```

The output is `bb.min.js` which has the problem described above.

### Quick note

If I compile it in `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` mode, then I get the expected output (minus all the public interfaces being renamed, which I don't want, and I don't want to export all of them, either). What I want to do is compile in `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` mode and white-space only (so I can offer the library as a un-minified/un-obfuscated as well).

Comment: What value are you expecting for COMPILED?

Comment: I expect the boilerplate goog stuff to be gone, and my code to be all in place. Right now it doesn't define the namespace, etc. It uses goog's base.js functionality to run my code.

Comment: Sound like you want to use ADVANCED mode and to export your interface, which you state you didn't want to do.  Why don't you want to export your interface?

Comment: I've tried that option, but my codebase turned out just as large (compiled output) with all the window[NS][Class] = (...) Entries. Not to mention the time it takes to maintain those. Since my project is just a standalone library, I'm not too concerned with squeezing every bit of compression and performance out of it. Simple_optimizations is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `--output_mode=compiled` should be `--output_mode="compiled"`

Here's what mine looks like that works:

```
python Z:\scripts\closure\closure\bin\calcdeps.py^
 --path=Z:\scripts\closure\^
 --output_mode="compiled"^
 --compiler_jar=Z:\scripts\closure\other\compiler.jar^
 --compiler_flag=--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS^
 --compiler_flag=--use_types_for_optimization^
 --compiler_flag=--warning_level=VERBOSE^
 --input=Z:\scripts\closure\other\soyutils_usegoog.js^
 --input=Z:\scripts\closure\closure\goog\deps.js^
 --input=utils.js^
 --input=main.js^
 --input=templates.soy.js^
 --output_file=main.min.js
```

Note that you would need to modify this to match your paths/files and that mine is meant for a windows environment, so replace the `^` with `\` and the backslashes with forward slashes for paths.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I edited my question to point out that if I compile in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode, it works. However, I'd like to have the code compiled in WHITESPACE_ONLY and SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS modes only. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira if you're using the closure library, you should be using advanced optimizations anyway. edit: If you want to provide this as a library for people, then provide your source, not the compiled version. People who would use your code would then need to compile it. (they would need to compile it in any event)

Comment: What about the case when I want to write a library and compile the code without any optimizations?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira Then just provide your source files. If you partially compile it, then it's useless to people without them having to compile it all the way anyway (the source would be like +150k).

Comment: I see your point. Maybe I should just take the time and export all the public interfaces... Do you think the flag output_mode is ignored if used in compilation_level < ADVANCED?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I don't think it's ignored because "compiled" isn't the only output option.  And yes, taking the time to export interfaces and or provide an externs file (probably your best option) is well worth the time.